# Custom HTML/PHP/Mysql form doesn't work in Joomla

Tags: php, html, mysql, joomla

I programmed a form for Joomla. It worked perfectly fine but now all of a sudden the PHP handling doesn't work properly. I tried dozen of things to make it work but it doesn't listen to me. Why?

Here's the code:

```
<?php
echo '<html>
      <table>
        <form method="post" action="post">
        <tr>
          <td>Uporabniško ime</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="up_ime" id="up_ime" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Origin ID</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="origin" id="origin" size="40">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Prijava"></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
        </table>

</html>';

mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("fifaslov_fut");

$up_ime = $_POST['up_ime'];  
$origin = $_POST['origin'];

if(empty($up_ime) || empty($origin)){
    echo("");
} else{
    $order = "INSERT INTO futliga_pc_prijava (up_ime, origin) VALUES ('$up_ime','$origin')";
    $result = mysql_query($order);
    echo("<br>Uspešno ste se prijavili!");
}
mysql_close;
?>
```

Comment: What did you change? "doesn't work properly" and " tried dozen of things" are both not enough information for anyone to help. You need to explain what you expected to happen what actually happened and what you tried. Also I don't understand what this has to do with Joomla, you have no joomla code there and are not using the Joomla form api.

Comment: this question contains a password, which is probably not intended by the original author.

Comment: yes sorry for the password I just copied it :)

Comment: I didn't change anything I programmed it just like that and it worked fine and all of a sudden it stopped working. I tried to change the method several times.

Comment: You need to include your error message. Just saying "It stopped working" doesn't help us to help you. Please review the [Minimal Standards](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you're not sure what ti provide

Comment: Removed your credentials

Answer (score -1):

You are not storing `connection Variable`

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","fifaslov_fut","bovo2978", "fifaslov_fut");
$up_ime = $_POST['up_ime'];  
$origin = $_POST['origin'];

if(empty($up_ime) || empty($origin)){
echo("");
} else{
$order = "INSERT INTO futliga_pc_prijava (up_ime, origin) VALUES ('$up_ime','$origin')";
$result = mysql_query($con, $order);
echo("<br>Uspešno ste se prijavili!");
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Just an Advice Use `mysqli`

Comment: Joomla has it's own API to connect to the database and get data. `mysqli_*` should not be used at all

Comment: Thank you. That's the problem :)